# is possible send data from an existing iOS App to a Watch OS 6 Independent App member of an app group?

Tags: ios-app-group, wcsession, watchos-6

I have an iOS app without their companion watch app, I tried to read data stored in the iOS app from my new watchOS 6 independent app.

Is there any option like:

```
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.myApp")!
```

but with WCSession or similar to read the described data?

Just to be clear, I generate images in my iOS device, and and save them locally (User Defaults). I used to get the data reading/saving it in an app group user defaults, then I have to read those images from a set of watch os 6 independent apps that are under my control.

Answer (score 0):

I need to provide an answer as I cannot comment.

I know this is for an independent app but since there isn't a lot meat on the bone of question

(E.g. what's the connection type/link? I assume we're talking 2 different OS therefor 2 different devices, so, through what type of networking will they share/push information? Also, what's the purpose? Is it for notification purposes? Or do you want to pass dynamic values?)

If it's for notifications, you could use PushBullet.

If it's to pass other information via LAN = Check with Apple Dev support, I'm fairly certain they will know if there's a option to pass values cross-LAN.

If it's to pass information via WAN = You will need a link access point. E.g. a shared server where watchOS app & iOS app are connected to. From there you can easily pass the values around.